# How to traverse through inner Json array and retrieve the values

Tags: java, json, api, rest-assured

I have an response Json given below I need to retrieve the values of price from inner "childItems" Array and sum it up to get the total price = 7.7

Below is the java code i just tried with which I guess is bit wrong.

```
List<Float> items_price = response.jsonPath().getList("items.childItems.price");
   float Total_Price=0;
   for(int i=0;i<items_price.size();i++)
   {
      Total_Price = Total_Price + items_price.get(i);
   }
   Total_Price = Total_Price + response.jsonPath().getFloat("tax");
```

**Below is the Response Json
==========================**

```
{
      "brandId": "HAL",
      "sellingChannel": "WEBOA",
      "subTotal": 7.19,
      "total": 7.7,
      "items": [
        {
          "lineItemId": 101,
          "description": "Apple Buffet",
          "price": 0,
          "priceType": null,
          "productId": "HAL-itm-000-057",
          "childItems": [
            {
              "lineItemId": 102,
              "description": "Apple",
              "price": 3.31,
              "priceType": null,
              "productId": "HAL-itm-000-055",
              "childItems": [],
              "modifierGroups": [
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-001",
                  "modifiers": [
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-006-011",
                      "price": 2,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-002",
                  "modifiers": []
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-003",
                  "modifiers": [
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-008-011",
                      "price": 0.29,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    },
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-008-004",
                      "price": 0,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    },
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-008-005",
                      "price": 0.29,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-004",
                  "modifiers": [
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-009-013",
                      "price": 0,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-005",
                  "modifiers": []
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-006",
                  "modifiers": []
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-008",
                  "modifiers": [
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-013-007",
                      "price": 0,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-010",
                  "modifiers": [
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-015-001",
                      "price": 0,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "quantity": 1,
              "note": null
            },
            {
              "lineItemId": 103,
              "description": "Vegetable Fires",
              "price": 1.99,
              "priceType": null,
              "productId": "HAL-itm-002-002",
              "childItems": [],
              "modifierGroups": [
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-006",
                  "modifiers": []
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-005",
                  "modifiers": []
                }
              ],
              "quantity": 1,
              "note": null
            },
            {
              "lineItemId": 104,
              "description": "Coca-Cola®",
              "price": 1.89,
              "priceType": null,
              "productId": "HAL-itm-003-001",
              "childItems": [],
              "modifierGroups": [
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-011",
                  "modifiers": [
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-016-001",
                      "price": 0,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "description": null,
                  "productId": "HAL-prg-001-012",
                  "modifiers": [
                    {
                      "productId": "HAL-itm-017-001",
                      "price": 0,
                      "priceType": null,
                      "actionCode": null,
                      "quantity": 1
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "quantity": 1,
              "note": null
            }
          ],
          "modifierGroups": [],
          "quantity": 1,
          "note": null
        }
      ],
      "fulfillment": {
        "fulfillmentType": "TimePickup",
        "asap": true,
        "pickupTime": null,
        "storeLocation": {
          "locationId": "99983"
        }
      },
      "tallyTime": "2018-03-25T12:41:29.949Z",
      "tax": 3.51
    }
```

Please let me know your thoughts on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried the below approach and it worked for me.

JSONObject results = new JSONObject(response.asString());

```
    JSONArray childItems= results.getJSONArray("items").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("childItems");
    
    float Total_Price =0;
    for(int i=0;i<childItems.length();i++)
    {
        //scenario.write(childItems.toString());
        scenario.write(+i +" : "+childItems.getJSONObject(i).getFloat("price"));
        
        Total_Price = Total_Price + childItems.getJSONObject(i).getFloat("price");
    }
    
    Total_Price = Total_Price + response.jsonPath().getFloat("tax");
    
    Assert.assertEquals(Total_Price, response.jsonPath().getFloat("total"),"Total Price in response is not equal to sum of line items price plus tax");
```